# Android Time class - Milliseconds back to Time?

Tags: java, android, date, time

This is what I have... if I convert it to milliseconds I have to store it as long. I use Android API Time class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
long todayMillis = today.toMillis(false);
```

I would like to format it back after to readable version something like that (after getting teh milliseconds I save it to the database to retrieve it afterwards):

```
todayMillis.format("%k:%M %d.%m.%y");
```

But I can't do it so easily since I need to convert back to Time.. how can it be done?

Comment: Do you want to convert it into a string or back into the Time class?

Comment: Basically I want to show it as a string but I guess I have to get it back to Time in order to format it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new time object, then call [Time.set(long milliseconds)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#set%28long%29)

```
Time time = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimeZone());
time.set(todayMillis);
```

I don't think the original time zone is even needed as the milliseconds are in UTC, however I'm guess the `Time` object uses the passed time zone internally somehow.

Comment: You are right indeed... thank you, dont't know how I didn't read that from the manual myself!!!

Comment: Eh, this stuff is easy to overlook. Specially if you're staring at a screen all day!

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `today` object of type `Time` so there is no need to convert the millis back to time.  But if you must, `android.text.format.Time` contains a `set` method that takes `milliseconds` as a `long`.

```
Time newToday = new Time();
newToday.set(todayMillis);
newToday.format("%k:%M %d.%m.%y");
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#set%28long%29)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention I save to to database so I retrieve it as milliseconds late... *then* want to format it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Creates a new Calendar with the current Time
calendar.setTimeInMillis(todaysMillis);  // you can also put your millis in. Same effect.
String readableOutput = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +
            ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +
            " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
            "." + (1+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) +
            "." + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

For more Fields and Methods:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html